# How to extracting tags and attributes from a website in nodejs?

Tags: html, node.js, viewport, meta-tags

I wanted to extract the metatag and check whether 'viewport' is present in the meta tag in nodejs. I searched and couldn't find any efficient method. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a site providing programmers doing your job for you or helping you out in this general way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would be helpful:

```
function getMeta(){
    var  el = document.getElementsByTagName('head'),        
     ch =  el[0].children;

    for (let e=0; e<ch.length; e++) {           
        if ( ch[e].tagName.toLowerCase() === 'meta' && ch[e].getAttribute('name') === "viewport"){
            console.log(ch[e]);
        }
    }
}
```

and just call function as

```
getMeta();
```